# How do I replace certain parts of my string?

Tags: php, string, replace

How can I replace a certain part of my string with another one?

Input string:

```
"Hello, my name is Santa"
```

How can I change all `a`'s in my string with something else?

I think I need a `foreach` loop, but I'm unsure how to use it.

Comment: right.. and it should the first result also :)

Comment: Also, the deprecation of the `ereg_` family does not mean you cannot use regex in PHP. There is the [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) (`preg_`) family. The small differences should not keep you away from using it.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Not everyone finds manuals appealing. Although chances are this is a duplicate of a billion questions on stackoverflow, it's not a bad question for a Q&A site, right?

Comment: @zvran: When I can (literally) copy/paste the question title into Google and get definitive results, I'd say that the OP has not yet exhausted his resources. In one way, it's bad for the site to have more clutter (duplicate questions that are easily answered by simple research), but on the other hand it's potentially good for the next guy who *does* do a little research (more results). While the PHP manual may not be "appealing", it's certainly an authority and the first place you should check for simple questions like this. I see my comment was zapped, yet it contained a valuable link.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
strtr ($str, array ('a' => '<replacement>'));
```

Or to answer your question more precisely:

```
strtr ("Hello, my name is Santa", array ('a' => '<replacement>'));
```

Comment: Will this replace all the "a" chars in a string?

Comment: and i need to change $str to the variable i with the string i want to change on, right?

Comment: Yes, $str is the string to be processed, I've changed the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 27):

## Search & Replace

There are a few different functions/methods to replace a certain part of a string with something else, all with their own advantages.

##[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method <sub>(binary safe; case-sensitive)</sub>

**Arguments**

> mixed str_replace ( mixed **$search** , mixed **$replace** , mixed **$subject** [, int &$count ] )

`str_replace()` has 3 required arguments as you can see in the above definition with the correct order, all of which can take a string as also an array as argument!

**Search & Replace**

- <kbd>**search(string) AND replace(string)**</kbd> → Replaces the search string with the replace string.
- <kbd>**search(array) AND replace(string)**</kbd> → Replaces all search elements with the replace string.
- <kbd>**search(string) AND replace(array)**</kbd> → Throws you a notice: "Notice: Array to string conversion", because a replacement array for just one search string doesn't make sense, so it *tries* to convert the array to a string.
- <kbd>**search(array) AND replace(array)**</kbd> → Replaces each search element with the corresponding replace element (Keys are ignored!).
- <kbd>**search(more elements) AND replace(less elements)**</kbd> → Replaces each search element with the corresponding replace element (For the missing replace elements an empty string will be used).
- <kbd>**search(less elements) AND replace(more elements)**</kbd> → Replaces each search element with the corresponding replace element (Unneeded replace elements are ignored).

**Subject**

- <kbd>**subject(string)**</kbd> → Replacement is done for the subject string.
- <kbd>**subject(array)**</kbd> → Replacement is done for each array element.

**Code**

```
echo str_replace("search", "replace", "text search text");
echo str_replace(["t", "a"], "X", "text search text");
echo str_replace("search", ["replace1", "replace2"], "text search text");
echo str_replace(["a", "c"], ["X", "Y"], "text search text");
```

**Output**

```
text replace text
XexX seXrch XexX
Notice: Array to string conversion
text seXrYh text
```

**Notes**

1. Gotcha!

Important to know is that `str_replace()` works from left to right of the array. This means it can possible replace a value which you already replaced. For example:

```
    echo str_replace(array("a", "b"), array("b", "c"), "aabb");
    //Probably expected output: bbcc
    //Actual output:            cccc
```

2. Case insensitive

If you want to make the search case insensitive you can use [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) (Notice the `i` for case-**i**nsensitive).

3. Multidimensional array

`str_replace()`/`str_ireplace()` does NOT work for multidimensional arrays. See this [manual comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#100871) for such an implementation. Of course you can also replace `str_replace()` with `str_ireplace()` for case-insensitive.

If you want to put everything together and create a function that also works for multidimensional arrays case-insensitive you can do something like this:

```js
<?php 
function str_ireplace_deep($search, $replace, $subject) 
{ 
if (is_array($subject)) 
{ 
    foreach($subject as &$oneSubject) 
        $oneSubject = str_ireplace_deep($search, $replace, $oneSubject); 
    unset($oneSubject); 
    return $subject; 
} else { 
    return str_ireplace($search, $replace, $subject); 
} 
} 
?>
```

##[`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) method <sub>(50% binary safe; case-sensitive)</sub>

**Arguments**

> string strtr ( string **$str** , string **$from** , string **$to** )

> string strtr ( string **$str** , array **$replace_pairs** )

The function either takes 3 arguments with a from and to string or it takes 2 arguments with a replacement array `array("search" => "replace" /* , ... */)`, all of which you can see in the above definition with the correct order.

**2 Arguments**

It starts to replace the longest key with the corresponding value and does this until it replaced all `key => value` pairs. In this case the function is binary safe, since it uses the entire key/value.

**3 Arguments**

It replaces the from argument with the to argument in the subject *byte by byte*. So it is not binary safe!

If the from and to arguments are of unequal length the replacement will stop when it reaches the end of the shorter string.

**Subject**

It doesn't accept an array as subject, just a string.

**Code**

```
echo strtr("text search text", "ax", "XY");;
echo strtr("text search text", ["search" => "replace"]);
```

**Output**

```
teYt seXrch teYt
text replace text
```

**Notes**

1. Gotcha!

Opposed to `str_replace()`, `strtr()` does NOT replace replaced strings. As an example:

```
    echo strtr("aabb", ["a" => "b", "b" => "c"]);
    //If expecting to replace replacements: cccc
    //Actual output:                        bbcc
```

Also if you want to replace multiple things with the same string you can use [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to fill up your replacement array with the value.

2. Case insensitive

`strtr()` is NOT case-insensitive NOR is there a case-insensitive equivalent function. See this [manual comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#82051) for a case-insensitive implementation.

3. Multidimensional array

`strtr()` does opposed to `str_replace()` NOT work with arrays as subject, so it also does NOT work with multidimensional arrays. You can of course use the code above from `str_replace()` for multidimensional arrays and just use it with `strtr()` or the implementation of `stritr()`.

If you want to put everything together and create a function that also works for multidimensional arrays case-insensitive you can do something like this:

```js
<?php
if(!function_exists("stritr")){
function stritr($string, $one = NULL, $two = NULL){
/*
stritr - case insensitive version of strtr
Author: Alexander Peev
Posted in PHP.NET
*/
    if(  is_string( $one )  ){
        $two = strval( $two );
        $one = substr(  $one, 0, min( strlen($one), strlen($two) )  );
        $two = substr(  $two, 0, min( strlen($one), strlen($two) )  );
        $product = strtr(  $string, ( strtoupper($one) . strtolower($one) ), ( $two . $two )  );
        return $product;
    }
    else if(  is_array( $one )  ){
        $pos1 = 0;
        $product = $string;
        while(  count( $one ) > 0  ){
            $positions = array();
            foreach(  $one as $from => $to  ){
                if(   (  $pos2 = stripos( $product, $from, $pos1 )  ) === FALSE   ){
                    unset(  $one[ $from ]  );
                }
                else{
                    $positions[ $from ] = $pos2;
                }
            }
            if(  count( $one ) <= 0  )break;
            $winner = min( $positions );
            $key = array_search(  $winner, $positions  );
            $product = (   substr(  $product, 0, $winner  ) . $one[$key] . substr(  $product, ( $winner + strlen($key) )  )   );
            $pos1 = (  $winner + strlen( $one[$key] )  );
        }
        return $product;
    }
    else{
        return $string;
    }
}/* endfunction stritr */
}/* endfunction exists stritr */

function stritr_deep($string, $one = NULL, $two = NULL){
if (is_array($string)) 
{ 
    foreach($string as &$oneSubject) 
        $oneSubject = stritr($string, $one, $two); 
    unset($oneSubject); 
    return $string; 
} else { 
    return stritr($string, $one, $two); 
} 

}
?>
```

##[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) method <sub>(binary safe; case-sensitive)</sub>

**Arguments**

> mixed preg_replace ( mixed **$pattern** , mixed **$replacement** , mixed **$subject** [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )

`preg_replace()` has 3 required parameters in the order shown above. Now all 3 of them can take a string as also an array as argument!

**Search & Replace**

- <kbd>**search(string) AND replace(string)**</kbd> → Replaces all matches of the search regex with the replace string.
- <kbd>**search(array) AND replace(string)**</kbd> → Replaces all matches of each search regex with the replace string.
- <kbd>**search(string) AND replace(array)**</kbd> → Throws you a warning: "Warning: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array", because a replacement array for just one search regex doesn't make sense.
- <kbd>**search(array) AND replace(array)**</kbd> → Replaces all matches of each  search regex with the corresponding replace element(Keys are ignored!).
- <kbd>**search(more elements) AND replace(less elements)**</kbd> → Replaces all matches of each search regex with the corresponding replace element(For the missing replace elements an empty string will be used).
- <kbd>**search(less elements) AND replace(more elements)**</kbd> → Replaces all matches of each search regex with the corresponding replace element(Unneeded replace elements are ignored).

**Subject**

- <kbd>**subject(string)**</kbd> → Replacement is done for the subject string.
- <kbd>**subject(array)**</kbd> → Replacement is done for each array element.

Please note again: The search must be a regular expression! This means it needs delimiters and special characters need to be escaped.

**Code**

```
echo preg_replace("/search/", "replace", "text search text");
echo preg_replace(["/t/", "/a/"], "X", "text search text");
echo preg_replace("/search/", ["replace1", "replace2"], "text search text");
echo preg_replace(["a", "c"], ["X", "Y"], "text search text");
```

**Output**

```
text replace text
XexX seXrch XexX
Warning: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
text seXrYh text
```

**Notes**

1. Gotcha!

Same as `str_replace()`, `preg_replace()` works from left to right of the array. This means it can possible replace a value which you already replaced. For example:

```
    echo preg_replace(["/a/", "/b/"], ["b", "c"], "aabb");
    //Probably expected output: bbcc
    //Actual output:            cccc
```

2. Case insensitive

Since the search argument is a regular expression you can simply pass the [`flag i`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for case-insensitive search.

3. Multidimensional array

`preg_replace()` does NOT work for multidimensional arrays.

4. Backreference

Be aware that you can use `\\n`/`$n` as backreference to your capturing groups of the regex. Where `0` is the entire match and `1-99` for your capturing groups.

Also if the backreference is immediately followed by a number you have to use `\${n}`.

5. Replacement / "The /e modifier is deprecated"

The replacement in `preg_replace()` can't use callback functions as replacements. So you have to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Same when you use the modifier `e` and get "Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead". See: [Replace preg_replace() e modifier with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15454220/3933332)

If you want to put everything together and create a function that also works for multidimensional arrays case-insensitive you can do something like this:

```js
<?php
function preg_replace_deep($search, $replace, $subject) 
{ 
if (is_array($subject)) 
{ 
    foreach($subject as &$oneSubject) 
        $oneSubject = preg_replace_deep($search, $replace, $oneSubject); 
    unset($oneSubject); 
    return $subject; 
} else { 
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject); 
} 
} 
?>
```

##Loops [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) / [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) / [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) method <sub>(NOT binary safe; case-sensitive)</sub>

Now of course besides all of those functions you can also use a simple loop to loop through the string and replace each `search => replace` pair which you have.

But this gets way more complex when you do it binary safe, case-insensitive and for multidimensional arrays than just using the functions above. So I won't include any examples here.

---

## Affected String

Right now all methods shown above do the replacement over the entire string. But sometimes you want to replace something only for a certain part of your string.

For this you probably want to/can use [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php). Or another common method is to use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and apply the replacement only on that particular substring and put the string together afterwards. Of course you could also modify your regex or do something else to not apply the replacement to the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

str_replace is sufficient for simple replacement jobs (*such as replacing a single letter*), but the use of preg_replace is generally advised (*if you want something more flexible or versatile*), because it's flexible and versatile. And as the 'a' is just an example...:

```
$String = preg_replace('/<string>/','<replacement>',$String);
```

Or if you want multiple replacements at once:

```
$String = preg_replace(array('/<string 1>/','/<string 2>/'),array('<replacement 1>','<replacement 2>'),$String);
```

preg_replace can, unfortunately, be quite tricky to use. I recommend the following reads:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html

Also, if you decide to use str_replace(), and your replacement needs to be case-sensitive, you're going to need str_ireplace().

Comment: Do *not* use regular expressions for such simple tasks as replacing a single letter.

Comment: Which part of "str_replace is sufficient for simple replacement jobs" and "as the 'a' is just an example..." is unreadable or difficult to understand?

Comment: Because you are wrong. preg_replace() is *not* generally adviced. It *always* depends on the use case. Both your examples can easily be done with str_replace() instead of using regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, both examples can easily be done with str_replace(). The thing is, they are EXAMPLES. What's the point of writing a hard-to understand example by showing regex right away? That just turns people off. But I'll rephrase to humor you: preg_replace is generally advised unless you are looking for a REALLY SIMPLE AND EASY replacement which most programmers actually rarely need.

Comment: What's the point of showing preg_replace() *at all* when the questioned problem can be done with str_replace()? "most programmers actually rarely need"? Any reference for this claim?

Comment: I deemed showing preg_replace necessary because it was clear Stian Olsen was using 'a' as an EXAMPLE. Who knows what he was really trying to replace. I recommend you re-read his post. And "most programmers actually rarely need" is based on experience. If you don't believe it, why don't you look through joomla, drupal and similar, and just count the number of times each function is used? Don't get me wrong, str_replace does have it's uses, but you'll see preg_replace most of the time just because it has so many benefits.

Answer (score 1):

This can work also without of any of PHP string functions, here changing your 'a' to '&' ampersand character:

```
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++){
    if ($str[$i] == 'a'){
        $str[$i] = '&';
    }
}
echo $str;
```

Comment: You can't replace something in a string when you access it like an array with something more than 1 character long.