# How to replace one single quote by two single quotes in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, string, replace

I want to replace this using str_replace of PHP

> 'test

by

> test

EDIT

Done by this :

```
$test = str_replace("'", "''", "'test");
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the ' with a space or two single quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace certain parts of my string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163746/how-to-replace-certain-parts-of-my-string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try Function `STR_REPLACE`

**Syntax;**

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

**EX:**

```
$string = str_replace("'","''","'test");
```