# How to rename extension of file in directory with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a file in a directory 
name.processing and I want rename this file in name.processed

I have this code:

```
$fn1 = str_replace(".processed", ".processing", $fn);
rename($fn1,$fn);
```

$fn contain the complete path.

Why the file did not got rename in directory?

I think this is not a duplicate because i know how replace a part of string but i don't know how replace an extension of file in directory

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163746/how-to-replace-certain-parts-of-my-string

Comment: @Rizier123 please reconsider duplicate

Comment: @Machavity please reconsider duplicate

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not always predictable in parameter sequence, you should consult the documentation.

```
// processing -> processed
// str_replace($search, $replace, $haystack)
$fn_new = str_replace(".processing", ".processed", $fn);
// rename($oldname, $newname)
$rename = rename($fn,$fn_new);
echo "old: $fn, fn_new: $fn_new, rename: ", $rename ? 'success' : 'failure';
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

---

Edit:
If it still doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+rename

Comment: I don't know why but not work :-(

Comment: does it return success or failure?

Comment: obtain this: old: , fn_new: C:/wamp/www/prove/WORKSPACE/8bf50820/1467739866.processed, rename: failure

Comment: so the string rename is ok, but in directory the file is not renamed

Comment: Yeay, sorry typo:`old: $fn`. Now go for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+rename

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: @mydb you obtained `old: , fn_new: ...`. The text between `old: ` and `, fn_new` was empty, that was because I had a mistake in my answer. That mistake is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the paramters for `str_replace` backwards.http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Try `$fn1 = str_replace(".processing", ".processed", $fn);`

Comment: (You missed the rename being back to front)