# replace string with array value and add some text after and before array value

Tags: php, arrays

i need to replace string with array value and add some text after and before array value.
i tried to find solution in google and stackoverflow.but i failed.
Then I have a string, for example:

```
$string = "Hello...! :emo01:";
```

I have an array with Keys and Values, example:

```
$arr = array(":emo01:"=>"1f325", ":emo02:"=>"1f326", ":emo03:"=>"1f5b1");
```

and i need to code this function

```
function my_Function($arr,$string){

}
```

Would give the return as `"Hello...! <img src='http://www.domain.com/1f325.png' />"`.
how to write this 'my_Function' function.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8163746/3933332

Comment: Have you even looked at the link, basically duplicate, above?!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** work on **general case**.

```
$string = "Hello...! :emo01:";
$string2 = "Hello...! :emo01::emo02:";

$arr = array(":emo01:"=>"1f325", ":emo02:"=>"1f326", ":emo03:"=>"1f5b1");


function my_Function($arr, $string){

    $arrNewArray = [];

    foreach($arr as $key => $value ) {
        $arrNewArray[$key] = '<img src="http://yourdomain.com/'. $value .'.png" />';
    }

    return str_replace(array_keys($arrNewArray), $arrNewArray, $string);

}

echo my_Function($arr, $string);
echo my_Function($arr, $string2);
```