# How to reduce my str_replace php code?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How to reduce my str_replace php code ?

I want to remove aass until zass from

this is my php code, it's work good. But i want to reduce. how can i do ?

```
<?PHP
$str = str_replace('aass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('bass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('cass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('dass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('eass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('fass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('gass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('hass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('iass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('jass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('kass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('lass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('mass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('nass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('oass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('pass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('qass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('rass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('sass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('tass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('uass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('vass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('wass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('xass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('yass', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('zass', '', $str);
?>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8163746 you can simply use arrays for your arguments. You could also use a regex with `preg_replace()` if you want.

Answer (score 7):

Use a regex:

```
$res = preg_replace('~[a-z]ass~', '', $str);
```

The `[a-z]` character class matches any lowercase ASCII letter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3KWJh5/1).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/[a-z]ass/';
    $replacement = '';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to search.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$search = array("aass", "bass", "cass", "dass", "eass", "fass", "gass", "hass", "iass", "jass", "kass", "lass", "mass", "nass", "oass", "pass", "qass", "rass", "sass", "tass", "uass", "vass", "wass", "xass", "yass", "zass");
$str = str_replace($search, "", $str);
```

Alternatively, you can see Wiktor Stribiżew's answer, as that one is even more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Use with Array. Like below code:

```
$arrayKey = array('aass', 'bass', 'cass'.....);
$arrayReplace = array('','','');
$str = str_replace($arrayKey, $arrayReplace, $str);
```

OR

```
$arrayKey = array('aass', 'bass', 'cass'.....);
    $arrayReplace = "";
    $str = str_replace($arrayKey, $arrayReplace, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace`

Example:

```
echo preg_replace('/([s\S]*ass)/', '', $str);
```

`[s\S]*` includes anything, numbers, letters etc