# How to extract number from a currency grouped formatted string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have following grouped currency formatted string:

```
$str = "$1,000,000";
```

I want to just extract `1000000` in order to do some calculation. How can I achieve that? Is there any built-in PHP function to do so? Otherwise I may need to use some RegExp.

**EDIT**

This is not a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163746/how-to-replace-certain-parts-of-my-string) because here we have a currency grouped formatted string and not a straightforward simple text.

Comment: Use regex. That's the only way. Edit: str_replace can also work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace certain parts of my string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163746/how-to-replace-certain-parts-of-my-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might replace all non-digits with the empty string:

```
$str = "$1,000,000";
print(
  preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $str)
);
```

Of course, "non-digits" includes decimal points too. If you want to keep decimal points, then use a negated character set instead:

```
$str = "$1,000,000.00";
print(
  preg_replace('/[^\d.]+/', '', $str)
);
```

Comment: In `\D+`, is `+` necessary? I'm getting the same result even after removing it.

Comment: No, it's not necessary, but it might be a bit more efficient. For example, with `$$$$5`, rather than replacing a single `$` 4 times, it'll just replace `$$$$` once.

Comment: I think you are not right because if i had `$$$1,000,000` then result still would be `1000000` without using `+` in `\D`

Comment: The *result* will be the same, but there will be *fewer operations on the string* performed to get to that result. Like I said, it's not necessary, just more efficient.

Comment: @user5307298 `+` is one or more, without the quantifier you replace each character individually. Quantified is more efficient (although minimal in your example) see https://regex101.com/r/WbZnMk/2/ vs https://regex101.com/r/WbZnMk/1/

Comment: @user3783243 I know `+` is a quantifier but as I saw in your both examples, using `+` or not made no difference at all.

Comment: @user5307298 Look at the number of steps (top right) it takes. 18 vs. 14.

Comment: Be careful! This regexp will give you the wrong result if your input string contains a decimal value, for example `$str = "$1,000,000.00"`. The decimal point will also be stripped away and you'll end up with the number `100000000`. Perhaps you can guarantee that you'll never see numbers with decimal values for your case, but this is not a general purpose method to convert formatted currency strings to their numerical equivalents.

Comment: @user3783243 that i saw but practically visually does it make any difference since the result is same whether we use `+` or not. who one else is watching that `top right` difference on a website!

Comment: @SamChoukri yes i know but we really don't need any decimal place here - just the integer value that's all.

Comment: @user5307298 You said `without any solid example its hard to agree` I've given you the requested example. In your sample probably no difference would ever be noticed by a human, in larger examples it could be a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `str_replace` way, assuming that your digits only contain **$** and **,** *(or **.** if you include decimals)*

```
$toBeRemoved = array('$', ',');
$str = '$1,000,000';
$cleaned = floatval(str_replace($toBeRemoved, "", $str));
echo $cleaned;
```